# How should I understand this inversion?

Tags: meaning, subject-verb-inversion

I'm confused with the following sentence:

> In this section, we look at how the shuffle works, as a basic understanding would be helpful, should you need to optimize a Map-Reduce program.

How do I understand the grammar and the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Do you mean the "should you..." part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could rephrase the "*should you...*" part, it would become "*in case...*". So it would be like in the rephrased example below.

It basically means "*in the event of/that...*":

> In this section, we look at how the shuffle works, as a basic understanding would be helpful, **in case you needed** to optimize a Map-Reduce program.

See also this example taken from the NOAD:

> Should anyone arrive late, admission is likely to be refused.
>
> [*In case/in the event that someone arrives late, admission is likely to be refused.*]

Comment: I’d put it even more simply: in this construction *should you X* is essentially the same as *if you X*, though to be entirely correct one ought either to make it *if you should X* or to transform the verb in *X* to the subjunctive.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: yes, I don't know why Alenanno is talking about "in the event": the inverted conditional is always (I think) equivalent to an uninverted conditional with 'if'.

Comment: @Colin: Since that inversion refers to a "_possible event or situation_", I simply made that choice of words. Not to mention that "in the event of/that" is basically equivalent to saying "if" (speaking about the meaning). It's also listed in the [dictionary](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/event), see in "_Idioms_", the 4th one.

Comment: Yes, I'm not denying it has that meaning; I just think it's an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @Colin: Ah ok, it seemed otherwise. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Sorry.

Comment: @Colin: No problem at all! :)